# JavaScript change CSS properties

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

This set of code works fine, but I am wondering if we could use variable to store the stylesheet's property like letter-spacing, color, etc...

```js
function movespacing() {
  document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.color = 'black';
}
```

```css
h2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>letter-spacing: -5px</h2>
<input type="button" value="click to see animation" onclick="movespacing();" />
```

As you may know, once you've clicked on the button, color of the word 'letter-spacing' will change to black from whatever the previous color is.
Now, I did try store css property into some variable like

```
var cssColor = document.styleSheets.cssRules[0].style.color;
```

then...

```
cssColor = "green";
```

and it didn't work.. please tell me why

There is one more css property like letter-spacing which I also tried but, the console gave me an error about invalid left-handed value assignment:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.letter-spacing = '5px';
```

Comment: document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.letterSpacing = '5px';

Comment: this is the way we do in javascript.

Comment: actually, in css, you need to define like 'letter-spacing'

Comment: @user3505908 yes, but you want to do this in JavaScript, and attribute names are converted to camelCase here.

Comment: Regarding the first question: you just reassign a variable to a different value, why would it change the initial value?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to, and should not, manipulate styles by changing the stylesheet, except in special situations. I don't know what rule `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]` points to (and it could change depending on what stylesheets you load and the order of rules in them), but if you want to change the color of `h2` to black, the normal way to do this is CSS is the following.

```html
<h2 id="h2">
```

```css
.black { color: black; }
```

```js
document.getElementById('h2') . classList . add('black');
```

Depending on your browser, or whether or not you are using jQuery, there are different ways to add the class. For instance, you could use `$('#h2').addClass('black')` in jQuery.

To change the color back, instead of remembering the old value in the stylesheet, and changing the stylesheet back, you simply remove the `'black'` class.

There are a couple of other things you are doing wrong:

1. To access a property from the `style` object, you need to use the camelcased name, as in `style.letterSpacing`. Your approach (`style.letter-spacing`) would have resulted in a syntax error (the hyphen `-` would be interpreted as a minus sign).
2. You can't change an object's property by assigning it to a variable as you are doing (`var cssColor = ...`) and then changing that variable's value. To oversimplify a bit, JavaScript variables are not "pointers", at least not in the way you seem to intend.

Comment: > JavaScript variables are not "pointers". Primitives are not, whereas objects are passed by reference.

Comment: 'JavaScript variables are not "pointers"' - That's a bit disingenuous - variables whose values are primitives are not 'pointers', but any variable whose value is an object would be a 'pointer' of sorts, a reference.